# How to have a two headings in same line with css?

Tags: html, css

See this fiddle
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mW6Xp/7/)

**CSS:**

```
.containers {
width:100%;
height:auto;
padding:10px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}

#id4 {
float:right;
margin-right:0;
display:inline;
    border:5px solid red;
}

#id5 {
text-align:center;
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='containers'>
<div id='id4'>
margin-right:10px;
</div>
<div id='id5'>
    center-text;
</div>
```

In this fiddle I want center-text to be center of the page, not at the center between left-border and float element.

Comment: `display:inline-block;`..???

Comment: to have the two elements in the same line

Comment: ya, almost correct, but when resizing the window, both elements are overlapping and there is always horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @Lonely: The scroll bar was due to padding, I have corrected that in this [**update**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/mW6Xp/10/), but the overlapping still happens due to the absolute positioning. Would you be OK with adding this as an answer for now? I will let you know if I find a fix for the overlapping.

Comment: yes, this is the answer (ofcourse with overlapping issues). Thanks

Comment: But if I want the float element to have some space between right border, how can I get it

Comment: @Lonely: You can do that by adding `right:10px;` (Note: The element is no longer a float element :()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is one possible option by adding `position: absolute; right: 10px;` to the `id4` div. This will make the div always stay at 10px from the right margin. But it has to be noted that the element is no longer a float element.

**Note:** The texts would overlap if the result window is shrunk beyond a certain level. I will update the answer if and when I manage to find a fix for that.

```
.containers {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#id4 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#id5 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: @Lonely: Always glad to help mate. Btw, I had added the `box-sizing` property to fix the scroll bar issue. This [**link**](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) has more details about it.

Comment: Just want to ask about it, ok I'll check that link

Comment: If you like w3schools, you can refer to this [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) also.

Answer (score 0):

```
.containers {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

#id4 {
    float:right;
    margin-right:0;
    display:inline;
    border:5px solid red;
}
#id5 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mW6Xp/8/)**

Comment: try it resizing the result window, center text is not at the center of the page

Comment: @Lonely It is working for me. Can you try it in your actual code and try it in browser?